# Running git clone as www-data

Tags: permissions, git

Ok, so I am getting the following error while I am logged in as `www-data` user account:

```
www-data@server:~/html/poc/storage/app/projects$ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA.git /var/www/html/poc/storage/projects/dvwa
fatal: destination path '/var/www/html/poc/storage/projects/dvwa' already exists and is not an empty directory.
www-data@server:~/html/poc/storage/app/projects$ ls -al
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 nli www-data 4096 mar 17 21:02 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 nli www-data 4096 mar 17 20:29 ..
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to clone to a directory with files already in it. Git prefers to clone to an empty directory to avoid any conflicts or accidentally overwriting files.

Check the path '/var/www/html/poc/storage/projects/dvw' it already has files in it. If you cant see them try 'ls -a' to view hidden files (its possible you have an existing .git folder hidden in that directory)

EDIT:

You are looking in the wrong folder...
Upon re-reading your post it looks like you ran the following command `~/html/poc/storage/app/projects$ ls -al`... when you should have ran... `$ ls -al /var/www/html/poc/storage/projects/dvw`